# Running Linux application as another user other than root

Tags: database, linux, linux-kernel, embedded

I want to run the linux application to as another user ( Other then root ).
In my application we have written the socket program and i am using the raw socket to ping the database server. As we run the application as root then it is able to ping the server. but when it is run as normal user other then root then it is  not able to ping the database server.

Can you please tell how to run the process with normal user ?
How can we check process is running with which user ?

Thanks,

Comment: The tags on this question seem cluttered and don't make much sense.  If this is a linux kernel module, then you won't have this issue, but at the same time, why would it matter if you have to run as root on an embedded system?

Comment: People seem to be assuming the difficulty is about starting the program as another user, but I don't think that is an accurate reading of the question.  Instead, I believe it to be that the program *fails* when run as an unprivileged user (and thus very on topic here).  Likely difficulties are trying to do a privileged operation such as a literal ICMP ping, use raw sockets without CAP_NET_RAW, or use a privileged port number on the local end.  Posting the code immediately surrounding the failing syscal would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
sudo -u <username> <command ...>
```

You can view info about your process (including, among other things, the username of the owner) with:

```
ps -Af | grep <process name>
```

Also, non-root programs can't use raw sockets.  This would indicate a flaw in the design of your program.

Answer (score 1):

as already Wug answered use "sudo" to run as a different user (if permitted in sudoers). And if you want to see which user owns the process you can use a different tools: like "top" or "ps aux", etc